# A secure way of saving shiny sessions?

Tags: r, shiny

I built a (complex) shiny app. The user uploads some data, creates plots, does some time consuming calculations, etc.

All necessary data will be stored in a model object `model` (R6). In order to continue the work in the future, the user can download this model object (with `saveRDS`) and upload it again whenever he wants.

The drawback: Since the whole R6 model object `model` will be saved you could easily load it with `readRDS` and read the whole code structure of the model object. This isn't the result I wanted, but it's still acceptable.
The other point is more about a security question: Someone could change the code of the `model` object and upload it. Is it possible to write some piece of R code that would be critical to the server?

To avoid this drawback, I encrypt the model with "cyphr" before saving it with `saveRDS`. But in this case the file is much bigger! And that's not an acceptable solution.
Are there good ways for saving a shiny state / apps, or encrypt the object in a "light version"?

The following example could be used for saving and uploading (modified) R6 object.

```
library(shiny)
library(R6)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  test_object <- Test_object$new()

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "test.tst",
    content = function(file) {

      saveRDS(test_object, file = file)
    },
    contentType = "TST/tst"
  )

  observeEvent(input$upload, ignoreInit = T, {
    test_object <<- readRDS(input$upload$datapath)
    #print id
    print(test_object$id)
  })

  observeEvent(input$print, ignoreInit = T, {
    test_object$call_function()
  })

}

ui <- function(request) { 
  fluidPage(
    downloadButton("download"),
    fileInput("upload", "upload", accept = "tst"),
    actionButton("print","print")
  )
}


#R6 object
Test_object <- R6Class(classname = "Test_object", lock_objects = T,

   public = list(

     id = "5",

     # Change the content of this list with some critical code 
     # after reading the test.tst in r with readRDS(), save it with saveRDS and upload it
     list = list("Hi", " there!"),

     call_function = function(){
       print(self$list)
     }
   )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update:**

To avoid the security lack that someone could modified the model, I use a SHA256 checksum. Each saved model get an unique ID. The ID and the hash of the corresponding object will be saved in a database.

Something like this:

```
library(digest)

#R6 object
Test_object <- R6Class(classname = "Test_object", lock_objects = T,

                       public = list(
                         id = NULL,
                         list = list("Hi", " there!"),
                         call_function = function(){
                           print(self$list)
                         }
                       )
)


## Datebase
database <- list(id = c(0), hash = c(0))

# Object to be saved
new_object <- Test_object$new()

# get next id from db
next_id <- max(database$id) + 1

# set next_id to model
new_object$id <- next_id

# get sha of this object
sha <- digest(new_object, algo = "sha256")

# add id and sha to databse
database$id[length(database$id)+1] <- next_id
database$hash[length(database$hash)+1] <- sha

# write object
saveRDS(new_object, "object.abc")


# If someone uploads this file
uploaded_object <- readRDS("object.abc") 

# get id 
uploaded_id <- uploaded_object$id

# create sha again
uploaded_sha <- digest(uploaded_object, algo = "sha256")

# compare shas
sha_database <- database$hash[match(uploaded_id, database$id)]
if(uploaded_sha == sha_database) print("Uploaded object is valid!")
```

Comment: you can use `history()` function for that. find more info here [link](http://rfaqs.com/saving-and-loading-r-workspace)

Comment: Hm, I don't know how `history()` would be useful.

Comment: Could you maybe encrypt the RDS file instead of encrypting the model? The resulting file would probably be smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting the RDS file instead of the model object leads to a file that has similar size to the RDS file without encryption. (Using the package 'cyphr')

```
file = "test_object.abc"
saveRDS(test_object , file = file)
cyphr_key <- cyphr::key_openssl(openssl::aes_keygen())
cyphr::encrypt_file(file, dest = file, key = cyphr_key)
```

But I would recommend to use both a checksum and the encryption.